# Springboot properties is not able to resolve global properties

Tags: spring-boot, properties, global-variables

I have a below properties in my spring boot application.properties

```
qs.cloud.region=${awsRegion}
```

I am using ubuntu and tried below in terminal.

```
export awsRegion=ap-southeast-1
```

When I did echo $awsRegion I am able to get the value in terminal

But when start my spring boot application I am getting

```
Could not resolve placeholder 'awsRegion' in value "${awsRegion}"
```

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

**First**: Environment variables are case-sensitive. By convention, but not rule, environment variable names are **always capitalized**.

---

**Second**: export is a command Bash that used to set a variable. The variable **will be visible only for any subprocesses started from that instance of Bash.**

---

**Third**:
To make it more permanent, you can add it to your shell configuration file: `$HOME/.bashrc` or more globally in `/etc/environment`.

For example, `AWS_REGION=ap-southeast-1`

After adding this line, the changes won't reflect instantly in GUI-based systems. You have to exit the terminal or create a new one and on the server, log out the session and log in to reflect these changes.